# How to make self defined enum type in module available in julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to define an enum type in a module so I can use it in all my functions. When I export the module, I can only get the enum type, but the element in enumerate type can not be recognized.

```
module testaux

greet() = print("Hello World!")
@enum Stortype colMajor rowMajor
@enum Sorttype ascend descend nosort

end # module
```

after import testaux successfully, I can call greet() and recognize Stortype. But I failed to use Stortype to restrict my function argument by the following definition:

```
function t(a::Stortype)
    println(a)
end
```

```
t(colMajor)
```

will complain colMajor not defined.

Comment: Try `testaux. Stortype` in the definition of function `t`.

Comment: I would also sugest trying `t(testaux.colMajor)`

Comment: Just add an `export Stortype, Sorttype` before the end of the module.

Comment: @logankilpatrick Thanks, t(testaux.colMajor) works fine!

Comment: @laborg is more correct though. I think exporting is the real solution!

Comment: @laborg Hi, laborg, thanks, but still need testaux.colMajor for me

Comment: Yes, apparently you'll also need to export all enumerated values. Similar topic has been discussed here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/encapsulating-enum-access-via-dot-syntax/11785